# SQL query to find highest strike rate by a batsman in powerplay(1-6 over)

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
`select overs,(sum(batsman_runs)/count(batsman_runs))*100 as Strike_rate,batsman from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL where overs between 1 and 6 group by batsman;`

I tried this bit getting an error.
overs -- 1-20,
Table name = IPL_BALL_BY_BALL,
batsman_runs = runs of the batsman,
batsman - name of the batsman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing overs in group by. You should add overs only if you need strike rate for each over. In that case please try this,

```
select 
overs
,batsman
,(sum(batsman_runs)/count(batsman_runs))*100 as Strike_rate
from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL 
where overs between 1 and 6 
group by overs, batsman;
```

If you want to calculate this for the powerplay then try this,

```
select 
batsman
,(sum(batsman_runs)/count(batsman_runs))*100 as Strike_rate
from IPL_BALL_BY_BALL 
where overs between 1 and 6 
group by batsman;
```

Comment: strike rate formula = (total runs scored/total ball faced)*100 why the formula would be (sum(batsman_runs)/count(balls))*100

Comment: I think total runs scores is the sum of batsman_runs and extra runs. While calculating strike rate I think we should consider only the runs scored by batsman.